# C++ initializer lists with dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on an assignment for class.  We're working with dynamic arrays, and the assignment asks us to write code such that we're able to use an initializer list constructor for a dynamic array.  I'm somewhat familiar with dynamic arrays and initializer lists, but I've never really used them in conjunction.

```
arrayTest<int> testArr= {4, 13, 5};
```

Is the example line of code given (with `arrayTest` the class containing this code) the assignment hints that we should consider using the `std::copy()` algorithm within the definition of the constructor, but i'm a bit lost.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Define "a bit lost". What is your problem?

Comment: sorry, i should have clarified. i'm not quite sure how to create such a constructor that utilizes the copy algorithm. i know it's a vague issue, but i'm not sure how else i'm able to word it.

Comment: Call `std::copy`? If you don't know how to, read about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in a non C++11, this could help you get the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    int nums[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    std::vector<int> v_nums (5);
    std::copy (&nums[0], &nums[5], v_nums.begin ());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_nums.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v_nums[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```